# How to get mezzanine sidebar to autopopulate for blogposts

Tags: python, django, sidebar, mezzanine

I have a blog running mezzanine and I can't get the right side bar to auto populate after a blog post with the information about the blog post, like author, tags, etc. The only way I can get it to show at all it to manually edit the base.html file and add a widget for each field. Isn't there a way to automate this?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, mezzanine includes something similar to what you're asking, the `filter_panel.html` template. This is the template the blog app uses. In whatever template you're using, include this template in the `right_panel` block, eg:

```
{% block right_panel %}
{% include "blog/includes/filter_panel.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you're just using `base.html`, you can override the `right_panel` block by replacing it with just the above `includes` tag.

Hope that helps!